# FullCalendar doesn't add any event (week view, agenda view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've update `FullCalendar` version from v. 2.3.1 to 2.4.0, before all working well, but now In `week view` and `agenda view` I can't add the event. The thing is strange 'cause in the `month view` I see my appointments and other event. I'm using this code for add the event:

```
$.each(response, function(index, rsp) 
        {
              $.each(rsp.appointments, function(index, appointment)
              {               

                  var check = GeneralFunctions.checkOperatorExistence(myMap, appointment['provider']['first_name']);

                  if(check.length > 0)
                  {
                      var operatore_info = check.split(",");
                      var column_operator = Number(operatore_info[1]);

                        var event =
                        {
                              'id': appointment['id'],
                              'title': appointment['service']['name'] + ' - '
                              + appointment['customer']['first_name'] + ' '
                              + appointment['customer']['last_name'],
                              'start': appointment['start_datetime'],
                              'end': appointment['end_datetime'],
                              'allDay': false,
                              'color': '#' + appointment['res_id']['hex_color'],
                              'data': appointment,
                              'column': column_operator
                        };

                      calendarEvents.push(event);
                   }
              })
        });                         

        $calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', calendarEvents);
```

my code perform an ajax request and insert the appointment for each provider saved in my system. There's something wrong in my code probably for the version changed? I get any error in the system.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkmda709/32/)**

**UPDATE**

If I click on a specific day of Agenda view or week view I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>   fullcalendar.js:2026 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

**Import library**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/css/libs/jquery/fullcalendar.css" />

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/jquery/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/jquery/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>UI/multicolumn/fullcalendar-columns.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/jquery/fullcalendar-it.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/backend_calendar.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/css/custom/custom.css"</script>
```

May be help?

**INIT calendar settings**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        'defaultView': 'multiColAgendaDay',
        'height': BackendCalendar.getCalendarHeight(),
        'editable': true,
        'firstDay': 1,          //Lunedì
        'slotMinutes': 60,
        'slotDuration': '00:30:00',
        'slotLabelFormat': 'h(:mm)a',
        'timeFormat': 'H(:mm)',
        'allDayText': EALang['all_day'], 
        'columnFormat': 
        {
            'month': 'ddd',
            'week': 'ddd D',
            'day': 'dddd'
        },
        'titleFormat': 
        {
            'month': 'MMMM YYYY',
            'week': 'MMM D YYYY',
            'day': 'MMMM D YYYY'
        },
        'header': 
        {
            'left': 'prev,next today',
            'center': 'title',
            'right': 'multiColAgendaDay,multiColAgendaWeek,month'
        },
        'views':
        {
            'multiColAgendaDay':
            {
                'type': 'multiColAgenda',
                'duration': { days: 1},
                'columns': updated
            },
            'multiColAgendaWeek':
            {
                'type': 'multiColAgenda',
                'duration': { weeks: 1 },
                'columns': updated
            }
        },
```

I'm using an external resource for multicolumn like the following: https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-columns

Comment: Silly, but: probably looking in to the wrong week or wrong day?

Comment: Nope. I don't know if this may help but: if I click on a specific day of (week view or agenda view) I get this errors: Uncaught TypeError: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: Show your calendar init settings, please. Errors deep within fullCalendar classes indicate very likely a problem in setup

Comment: You can also check my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkmda709/32/

Answer (score 0):

It works with fullcalendar 2.3.1 (Your fiddle is using 2.4.0)

http://jsfiddle.net/jkmda709/34/

```
/*fullcalendar-columns

A FullCalendar extension that adds support for multiple columns (/resources) per day. Tested with FullCalendar v2.3.1, but likely to be compatible with other versions.*/
```

Comment: I need to use it 2.4.0 'cause I've a bug on the column. In particular when I drag an event on another column the column id returned is wrong. So I want to try the last version for check if this bug it's corrected. And also have another bug-fixes for the css. Could you help me to made this working on the last version?